# Vertical alignment in email template

Tags: html, css, html-email

I want to adjust the alignment of the image in the box so that the bottom of the image always sticks to the bottom of the box!

> **Important note:**
> These codes are for email template (So we can not use `display:flex/grid`, `position:absolue`, `margin-top`, `transform`, etc)

[image]

What I tried:

```
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>

        <div style="vertical-align: bottom">
          <img src="1.jpg" />
        </div>
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the alignment in the `<td>` or `<table>`. Outlook desktop treats `<div>s` as essentially inline, so it has no 'block' like properties such as alignment.

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <td style="vertical-align: bottom">
          <img src="1.jpg" />
```

A common technique to remove the spacing under the `<img>` is to add to its style `display:block` or `vertical-align:middle`. (Send a test to Gmail and you'll see what I mean.) Just confirming you *can* use vertical-align (any of top|middle|bottom - doesn't make a difference) for that at the same time. i.e.

```
<img src="1.jpg" style="vertical-align:middle" />
```